# How to give user permission on django admin site

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to give a user limited access to the admin site.

I logged in as a superuser, and gave the user staff status and the permissions over a model: "can add", "can change" and "can delete".

[image: Chosen user permissions dialog]

The problem is the user can log in to the site, but sees this message:

[image: "You don't have permission to edit anything."]

If I give him superuser status he can edit anything, but I want to give him limited access. Is there another option I must check before he can receive rights? I'm using Django 1.6.1.

Comment: Did you call `admin.autodiscover()` in your urls.py? What Django version are you on?

Comment: Yes, I added autodiscover method.
Django 1.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

The permissions I was giving the user, were on a model that was not registered to the admin. I was not aware that the permissions will be available even though the model is not registered.

Thank you for your tips.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of simple things you could check;

user is active?
the permissions you want to grant are 'chosen' i.e they appear in the right-hand 'chosen' column?

[image]

Comment: [user active](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p499xhwiy8ra9cv/is_staff.PNG)


[permissions](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5eu86dk65oksj7r/user%20permissions.PNG)

Checked the permissions after reloading the page...

Comment: I don't understand. I'm not allowed to comment ... but shouldn't answer either.