# Need to restrict the access for staff users to view and edit only their inputted data in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I need to restrict the access in the admin page like if a staff user is logging in the admin they need to see only their entry data's and can able to add or delete their data in the admin panel.

As I tried the below code in the admin.py still I could able to view and delete everyone's data.

**Admin.py**

```
admin.site.site_header = "Inhouse Project Management"
admin.site.site_title = "TimeSheet Admin Portal"
admin.site.index_title = "TimeSheet Administration"

TokenAdmin.raw_id_fields = ['user']

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(user=request.user)

#Admin SuperUser
@admin.register(User)

class UserAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','employee_name','email','billable_and_non_billable','designation')
    search_fields = ['employee_name']
    pass

@admin.register(Project)

class ProjectAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','project_name','client','start_date','end_date')
    search_fields = ['project_name']
    pass
```

**Urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="social_app/index.html")), #social_app/index.html
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),         #admin api
    path('api/',include(router.urls)),          #api
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),       #allauth
    re_path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),    #rest_auth
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    re_path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    #path('api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token),
    #path('api-token-auth/',CustomAuthToken.as_view()),
    #path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('auth/login/',TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('conso/',view),
    path('chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
]
```

**models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    
    
    BLOOD_GROUP_CHOICES = (
        
        ('a+','A+'),
        ('a-','A-'),
        ('b+','B+'),
        ('b-','B-'),
        ('ab+','AB+'),
        ('ab-','AB-'),
        ('o+','O+'),
        ('o-','O-')
        
    )
    
    
    BILLABLE_and_NON_BILLABLE_CHOICES=(
        
        
        ('Billable','Billable'),
        ('Non-Billable','Non-Billable')
    )



    employee_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dob=models.DateField(max_length=8) 
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254,default=None) 
    pancard=models.CharField(max_length=25,default=None)
    aadhar=models.CharField(max_length=20,default=None)
    personal_email_id=models.EmailField(max_length=254,default=None)
    phone = PhoneField(blank=True)
    emergency_contact_no=models.IntegerField(default=None)
    emergency_contact_name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    relation=models.CharField(max_length=25,default=None)
    blood_group=models.CharField(max_length=25,choices=BLOOD_GROUP_CHOICES,null=True)  
    designation=models.ForeignKey(Designation,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name="designation")
    billable_and_non_billable=models.CharField(max_length=25,choices=BILLABLE_and_NON_BILLABLE_CHOICES,default='Billable')
    joining_date=models.DateField(max_length=15,null=True)
    relieving_date=models.DateField(max_length=15,null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table ='User'
        
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee_name
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    #Email Notification
    def create(self, validate_data):
        subject = 'Your account was activated'
        plain_message = 'SAMPLE TEXT'
        from_email = 'demomaster147@gmail.com'
        to_email = validate_data['email']
        EmailThread(subject, plain_message, from_email, to_email).start()
        return User.objects.create(**validate_data)
```

I need to restrict the access for users to view and edit only their data in the admin panel. I dont know what needs to be updated to get that worked. Kindly help to resolve this issue.

**Updated code as per the answer**

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        user = request.user
        return qs if user.is_staff else qs.filter(user=user)

'''class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            return qs
        print(request.user)
        #return qs.filter(user=request.user)'''

#Admin SuperUser
@admin.register(User)

class UserAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','employee_name','email','billable_and_non_billable','designation')
    search_fields = ['employee_name']
    pass
```

Job model where the employee_name is linked under user field from the user model

```
class Job(models.Model):
    
    job_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    client=models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='client',default=None)
    project = ChainedForeignKey(Project,chained_field="client", chained_model_field="client",show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='user',default=None)
    hours=models.TimeField(null=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    end_date=models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
```

Comment: i tried it as per your answer but it is throwing an error as "TypeError at /admin/App/job/
super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type". Can you please check and help me on this

Comment: Revert your code and try to print `request.user`

Comment: can you please explain it brief i couldn't able to get it..Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove my code which I've provided before and try to print `request.user ` inside your **MyModelAdmin** after calling `qs = super().get_queryset(request)`

Comment: I done like this, def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            return qs
        print(request.user)
is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, what you get in terminal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242537/discussion-between-vinoth-kumar-and-ankit-tiwari).

Answer (score 1):

First you've to create a class that will handle displaying objects to respective user

```
class StaffAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(user=request.user)
```

then you've to register this class with your model where you want to add this functionality eg. if you want to display project of perticular user you've to register this class with **Project** model like this

```
admin.site.register(Project, StaffAdmin)
```

**Note**: If you've logged in as staff make sure you've given permission to your staff to (view, add, update, delete) projects or it will raise **`PermissionDenied`** error check how to add permissions to [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091816/how-to-give-user-permission-on-django-admin-site). You may want to add user's permission programaticlly then check [**`default-permissions`**`[Django-doc]`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions)

Comment: Still it is showing all the data's for the user's not the specific data that the user has entered or inputted.

Comment: I tried with changing the usernames similarly but still i couldn't able to view the data for that user. can you please help me with it

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom user model, i will put my code hope that help!

Crm views

```
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from .models import Lead
from .leadforms import LeadForm, CreatingUser
from django.views import generic
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

# Create your views here.
class signup(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'
    form_class = CreatingUser

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("LogInPage")

class leads(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = "crm/leads.html"
    queryset = Lead.objects.all()
    context_object_name = "leads"

class leadetails(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'crm/leadetails.html'
    queryset = Lead.objects.all()
    context_object_name = "lead"

class leadcreate(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'crm/leadcreate.html'
    form_class = LeadForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("LeadsPage")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        send_mail(
            subject = "A lead Has been Created!",
            message = f"Agent is :{requset.user.username}",
            from_email = "Test@test.com",
            recipient_list= ["Tesy2@test.com"]
        )
        return super(leadcreate, self).form_valid(form)

class leadupdate(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    template_name = 'crm/leadupdate.html'
    form_class = LeadForm
    queryset = Lead.objects.all()

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("LeadsPage")

class leadelete(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DeleteView):
    template_name = 'crm/leadelete.html'
    queryset = Lead.objects.all()

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("LeadsPage")
```

crm urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', LoginView.as_view(), name="LogInPage"),
    path('logout', LogoutView.as_view(), name="LogOutPage"),
    path('signup', views.signup.as_view(), name="SignUpPage"),
    path('leads', views.leads.as_view(), name="LeadsPage"),
    path('leads/<int:pk>', views.leadetails.as_view(), name="Leadetails"),
    path('leads-create', views.leadcreate.as_view(), name="LeadCreate"),
    path('leads/<int:pk>-update', views.leadupdate.as_view(), name="Leadupdate"),
    path('leads/<int:pk>-delete', views.leadelete.as_view(), name="Leadelete"),
]
```

crm models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_organisor = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_agent = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Agent(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Lead(models.Model):
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    passport_no = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, null=True, blank=True,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

def UserCreateSignal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

models.signals.post_save.connect(UserCreateSignal, sender=User)
```

Crm form

```
from django import forms
from .models import Lead
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UsernameField
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# Create your forms hear.

User = get_user_model()

class LeadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = (
            'full_name',
            'passport_no',
            'email',
            'number',
            'agent',
        )

class CreatingUser(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username",)
        field_classes = {'username': UsernameField}
```

Base html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load static %}
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'crm/images/favicon.ico' %}" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'crm/css/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    {% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
    {% else %}
    {% if request.user.is_organisor %}
    <a href="{% url 'SignUpPage' %}">Create a new user</a>
    <a href="{% url 'AgentsPage' %}">Agents</a>
    {% endif %}
    <a href="{% url 'LeadsPage' %}">Leads</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    Welcome {{ request.user.username }}
    <a href="{% url 'LogOutPage' %}">Logout</a>
    {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'LogInPage' %}">Login</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% block body %} {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

you can assign different roles like is_organisor, is_agent in above code and you can restrict them from accessing and can edit in django admin

Reference images
[Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27CTJ.jpg)

[2nd permission ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ktPx.jpg)

**Note:** don't copy and past it's an incomplete code